# Call a Ionic provider function from global javascript scope

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, flutter-web

I want to call a function (TagDataSubscriber.next) from a global scope JavaScript function. It's a bridge between Flutter app and my Ionic app. Any idea how to achieve that? I found a app-injector somewhere in the internet, but it won't work.

Regards,
Markus

```
import {Injector} from '@angular/core';

let appInjectorRef: Injector;
export const AppInjector = (injector?: Injector): Injector => {
  if (injector) {
    appInjectorRef = injector;
  }
  return appInjectorRef;
};
```

Provider file:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Subscriber} from 'rxjs/Subscriber';
import {AppInjector} from "../../app/app-injector";

/* function called by Flutter if a NFC tag was detected */
window["nfcTagReceived"] = function (nfcTag) {
  let injector = AppInjector();
  let nfcService = injector.get(NfcServiceProvider);
  nfcService.TagDataSubscriber.next(nfcTag);
}

@Injectable()
export class NfcServiceProvider {
  private nfcAvailable: boolean = false;
  private tagDataSubscriber: Subscriber<any>;
  private tagRead: Observable<number> = new Observable<number>(
    observer => this.tagDataSubscriber = observer
  );

  public get TagDataSubscriber(): Subscriber<any> {
    return this.tagDataSubscriber;
  }

  public get TagRead(): Observable<number> {
    /*Uncomment*ReadNfcOnce.postMessage("");*Uncomment*/
    return this.tagRead;
  }

  public get NfcAvailable(): boolean {
    return this.nfcAvailable;
  }

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

Comment: When you say "global scope" what do you mean? "window" and "document" are global scope and available from any Ionic page. Therefore, if I'm reading correctly you should simply be able to call window.nfcTagReceiver() from your Ionic file.

Comment: It‘s the other way round. Flutter is calling the window["nfcTagReceived"] function, which is defined on the window object. That‘s working fine. But inside that function i need to call a function which is defined inside NfcServiceProvider.  In my case i want to call the next() function from the tagDataSubsciber object.

Comment: why don't you just expose that public function to the window object from Ionic at init? Can't you just do something like window["TagDataSubscriber"] = this.TagDataSubscriber in the constructor of NfcServiceProvider?

Comment: Good idea! I gave it a try. After adding a provider for window, it worked.

    {provide: 'Window', useValue: window}


    constructor(@Inject('Window') private window: any) 
        {window.nfcTagReceived =    this.TagDataSubscriber;
    }


Now I'm hanging at the point, that the call of 
this.tagDataSubscriber.next(nfcTag);
is not notifying the subscriber.

Comment: Ok, it's not working, because 'this' is null within the TagDataSubscriber function.

Comment: Here is a gist with the wrapped up problem description.
https://gist.github.com/markus-fischbacher/d2ffb49f9e5f5e706bd49246c904941c

Comment: Finally it's working. It's important to put the this-pointer of the required service onto the window object. E.g. window["NfcServiceProvider"] = this; And in Flutter you have to call the function like this: runJavascript('window.NfcServiceProvider.TagDetected("$nfcId")'); That's all.